# Circles inside circles problem

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

With these two circles, I have managed to find the area of the shaded region. However, I assumed that the diameter of the outer circle was equal to the sum of the diameters of the two inscribed circles.

I can't, however, convince myself mathematically why that must be the case?

Answer (score 2):

If two circles are tangent to each others at a point $M$, then their centers lie on the line that is orthogonal to the tangent at $M$. So the three tangencies show that the centers are on the same line.

Comment: Your claim is correct. But it is not the case here. Btw, problem is not well defined. See [Pappus chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus_chain) for counter-example. (Consider any other circle in the grey area)

Comment: @ACB The three tangents are vertical here. At least it seems so.

Comment: That's what I meant. It seems so, but not stated. The OP is believing that it should be always true, which is a wrong idea.